# How to write decorator in typescript for storybook?

Tags: typescript, storybook, react-tsx

I am new to storybook as well as typescript, I am stuck, when creating a decorator which takes two parameters Story and context.

```
const CustomDecorator = (Story, context) => {
  console.log("My Decorator");
  return (
      <Story />
  );
};

const preview: Preview = {
  decorators: [CustomDecorator],
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/,
      },
    },
  },

  globalTypes: {
    theme: {
      description: 'Global theme for components',
      defaultValue: 'light',
      toolbar: {
        // The label to show for this toolbar item
        title: 'Theme',
        icon: 'circlehollow',
        // Array of plain string values or MenuItem shape (see below)
        items: ['light', 'dark'],
        // Change title based on selected value
        dynamicTitle: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

It shows me the following error:

```
Failed to compile.
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "," (8:13)
storybook/preview.ts undefined

   6 |   console.log("My Decorator");
   7 |   return (
>  8 |       <Story />
     |              ^
   9 |   );
  10 | };
  11 |
```

And when hovering on `<Story />` in vscode, it says
*'Story' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Story'?*

**NOTE: I am writing a global decorator.**

I have tried to search on the internet, but I have not found much clue to get resolved.

Comment: The error you are describing doesn't seem to match the error you put in the code block....  The error seems to be telling you exactly what is wrong. Syntax, not type....

Comment: @harsh-narwariya Can you rename your `.storybook/preview.ts` file to `.storybook/preview.tsx`? Let me know if if that fixes your issue.

Comment: @RobinThomas
Tried changing the ts to tsx, still error
'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.

Comment: @ptierno See the first error is of terminal which is coming at compilation and second one is the suggestion of VSCode (Visual Studio Code)

Comment: Can you share your `tsconfig.json`? Also, is the error from VS Code solved now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:
First, rename your .storybook/preview.ts file to .storybook/preview.tsx.
Then, if you see the error 'React' refers to a UMD global, import React from "react" will solve the problem.

My current preview.tsx file:

```
import React from "react";
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import theme from "../src/theme";

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/,
      },
    },
  },
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Story />
      </ThemeProvider>
    ),
  ],
};

export default preview;
```